# How to get a reciprocal plot from x and p(x)?

Tags: distributions, matlab

Let's say that I have a picture like the one in figure. This look like an histogram, but actually is not, in the sense that I did not produce the figure starting from a dataset of values. In fact, I only have the probability (the y axis) for each bar. I also have the center point of each bin, and the bin width of each bin. Notice that the graph is normalized such that the area under the bins is equal to one.

[image]

What I want to do now, is to calculate the reciprocal of this probabilities. Usually I would use this formula:

$g(y) = \frac{ 1 }{ y^2 } f\left( \frac{ 1 }{ y } \right) $

But I cannot do that now, since I do not want to assume any f(x). Having an histogram, I would just plot the (1./dataset) to get the reciprocal (in histogram form), and then I would normalize (assuming that the original dataset was not already normalized like the one in the example), so to have a good approximation of the rate distribution.
However, in this case, I don't have the dataset. I only have the y points (the p(x), actually) and the x (bin center for each bin).

I have been adviced to use the following formula (in MATLAB): 
plot(1./x, y)
And this will give me a function with the same shape as the reciprocal function, but not normalized. I *think* I could take this result and normalize it, and that should work fine. However, I wonder if there is another method that uses only the x and the p(x) in order to get the reciprocal values.

Thank you.

Comment: The phrase "*reciprocal of this probabilities*" is unclear. What is it you want? It seems that a sample was taken, but from which you have only a histogram. Do you want to get some representation (say a histogram-estimate) of the distribution of the inverse of the random variable represented by the sample?

Comment: Hi Glen_b, you interpretation is correct, sorry if I was unclear. However, please notice that my histogram does not represent the frequency but the probabilities. (maybe a better rapresentation would NOT be an histogram, but a point plot graph, where each point is the center of the shown bin (x) and the heigth of the bin (y) ).
Is  it clearer now?

Comment: It's a histogram of a population distribution? When you describe it as a probability, how is that probability obtained?

Comment: This is an histogram obtained by the method of vincentizing (described in the Ratcliff's paper "Group reaction time distributions and an analysis of distribution statistics", 1979). Shorltly, this method group together different samples coming from the same family distributions but with different parameters. With the vincentizing, I calculate the quantiles (using something like 50 quintiles in the graph) of each dataset and average across quantiles. 
With this method I can get a distribution with (more or less) the same shape of the family distr. It's a way to group data.

Comment: After I have done that, I normalized the quantiles so that the total area is equal to one. This is what the graph represents.

Comment: I am confused by your statement that the plot is "not a histogram," because to all appearances it is one. Each bar spans an interval $(x_i,x_{i+1}]$ and, by virtue of its height $y_i$, it represents a probability $p_i=y_i(x_{i+1}-x_i)$. If you want to represent the same information on a reciprocal axis you will therefore draw a bar spanning the interval $[1/x_{i+1},1/x_i)$. Necessarily its height $y_i^\prime$ will be determined by its area (which must remain unchanged), whence $y_i^\prime=p_i/(1/x_i-1/x_{i+1})$ = $x_ix_{i+1}p_i/(x_{i+1}-x_i)$ = $x_ix_{i+1}y_i$. What, then, is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could hack this.

You could create an empirical CDF using a running-sum along the probability density graph that you have created.  You can then fit it using a smoothing spline - this gives you an analytic function that can be evaluated, or whose derivative can be computed, at each of the sample locations.

You could also use a uniform random number generator and the empirical CDF to "resample" the space and generate a sample set from which a conventional histogram can be generated.

Yes its a hack.  I'm not sure if it does exactly what you are looking for.
Best of luck.